# Redisplay Video Thumbnail after User Taps Done Exiting Fullscreen - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a timeline using UITableView that displays video thumbnail images. The user can tap on a video thumbnail image and it opens the video fullscreen and plays. When the user taps the done button, the user is returned to the timeline. Now the video thumbnail is gone and the user sees the video they were watching and where they left off. I want it where the user taps the done button and it brings them back to the timeline and it displays the video thumbnail image like it was before playing the video fullscreen. Below is some code:

```
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderPhoto"];

        if (object) {

            //The below line displays the users video thumbnail on the timeline.
            //The following 2 lines is what fills the display cell that shows the photo.
            cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

            //The below line is what displays the video thumbnail on the home timeline.
            cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:@"videoThumbnail"];
            [cell.imageView loadInBackground];

            PFFile *video =[object objectForKey:@"file"];
            [video getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%li.m4v", (long)cell.mediaItemButton.tag];
                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:string];
                    [data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
                    NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];
                    //The below line is what displays the full size movie and plays it on the home timeline.
                    [cell.movie setContentURL:movieUrl];
                }
            }];

        }
        return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by adding this line to mpmovieplayer done button:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```